# how to pass data from service to component

Tags: angular

In a mean4 app i get loged-in and get a respose..

how do I use the data in my component

```js
login(currenuser){

  this.http.post(`http://localhost:3000/users/login`,currenuser,{responseType: 'text'})
  .subscribe((data:any) => {

      //  this.userToComponent=data;
      //  console.log(this.userToComponent)

    }
  )
}
```

Comment: Don't subscribe in the service. Return the observable. It's up to the component to subscribe, and thus do whatever it wants with the emitted event.

Answer (score 0):

In your service :

```
login(currenuser){

     return this.http.post(`http://localhost:3000/users/login`,currenuser {responseType: 'text'})
     .map(
            (response: Response) => { 
            return {response : response}

            });
```

Now in your component.ts subscribe the response

```
constructor(private router: Router, private loginService: LoginService) {}
    login(){
        this.loginService.login(currenuser)
    .subscribe(
    response => {
    console.log(response)
    });
    }
```